# PHP- HTML form radio button value always empty

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have designed a contact form and I use it to send submitted data to my email address using PHP mailer. All the other inputs like 'text', 'textarea', 'select' works fine. But the radio button I used in the form always returns empty value. I use POST method.

Here is my HTML form code,

```
<form action="php/get-a-quote.php" id="contactForm" type="post" >
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Your name *</label>
    <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Your email address *</label>
    <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your company name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="company_name" id="company_name">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Project Description *</label>
    <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your project description." rows="10" class="form-control" name="project_description" id="project_description"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Type of website</label>
    <select data-msg-required="Please enter the type of website." class="form-control" name="type_of_website" id="type_of_website">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
      <option value="Portfolio">Portfolio</option>
      <option value="Blog">Blog</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Expected time-frame for completion</label>
    <select data-msg-required="Please enter the expected time-frame for completion of your project." class="form-control" name="time_frame" id="time_frame">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1 week">1 week</option>
      <option value="2 weeks">2 weeks</option>
      <option value="3 weeks">3 weeks</option>
      <option value="more">more</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Need hosting and domain setup?</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="domain_radios" id="inlineRadio1" value="yes" > Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="domain_radios" id="inlineRadio2" value="no"> No
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Need social pages(fb, twitter, etc)?</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="social_radios" id="inlineRadio3" value="yes" > Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="social_radios" id="inlineRadio4" value="no" > No
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Your Request" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my PHP code. It is a separate file 'contact-form.php'

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address below.
$to = 'myemailgoeshere';


$subject = $_POST['company_name'];

if($to) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$fields = array(
    0 => array(
        'text' => 'Name',
        'val' => $_POST['name']
    ),
    1 => array(
        'text' => 'Email address',
        'val' => $_POST['email']
    ),
    2 => array(
        'text' => 'Company Name',
        'val' => $_POST['company_name']
    ),
    3 => array(
        'text' => 'Project Description',
        'val' => $_POST['project_description']
    ),
    4 => array(
        'text' => 'Type of Website',
        'val' => $_POST['type_of_website']
    ),
    5 => array(
        'text' => 'Time Frame',
        'val' => $_POST['time_frame']
    ),
    6 => array(
            'text' => 'Domain Radios',
            'val' => $_POST['domain_radios']
    ),
    7 => array(
            'text' => 'Social Radios',
            'val' => $_POST['social_radios']
    )
);



$message = "";

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'],     ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
}

$headers = '';
$headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
} else{
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
}

echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

$arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
echo json_encode($arrResult);

}
?>
```

This is my var_dump

```
array(8) { 
[0]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(4) "Name" ["val"]=> string(8) "UserName" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(13) "Email address" ["val"]=> string(15) "email@email.com" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(12) "Company Name" ["val"]=> string(14) "Sample Company" } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(19) "Project Description" ["val"]=> string(22) "Description goes here." } 
[4]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(15) "Type of Website" ["val"]=> string(5) "Sales" } 
[5]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(10) "Time Frame" ["val"]=> string(7) "2 weeks" } 
[6]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(13) "Domain Radios" ["val"]=> NULL } 
[7]=> array(2) { ["text"]=> string(13) "Social Radios" ["val"]=> NULL } 
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I have tried everywhere and browsed through enough posts. But I'm not able to figure this out.

FYI, I used a template to edit the website and it is bootstrap based, if that helps.

Comment: What kind of info do should I post?

Comment: You should make sure your second `<input>` tag is closed

Comment: The code here is fine. The problem is elsewhere. Show more code - you might be setting up the form wrong or something else...

Comment: What does your code look like when you send the mail? What does `print_r($fields);` display?

Comment: i have edited my post. pl take a look

Comment: @user3626796 Are those inputs inside your form? Can you update your post with the result of `var_dump($_POST);` to confirm the data you're expecting is being sent as POST.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna. Yes those inputs are inside the form. I get all other values in the array perfectly in my mail, except the radios.

Comment: Works fine here too. Are you sure you uploaded the newest version of it as well as pointing to the right file(s)?

Comment: Yeah. That's why other inputs are being sent to my mail.

Comment: Please post the var_dump result in a _readable_ fashion – put a `<pre>` element around it, or copy it from the “view source” display in your browser, and format it properly here.

Comment: Yeah. sorry for that. My first post in SO. I edited it.

Comment: Can you try the same forms without any of the bootstrap / template js and css applied? Just the raw HTML in its own page, and then `var_dump($_POST);` the result once you've sent your POST data.

Comment: Most likely that you HTML is faulty, so that your radio buttons end up _not_ being inside the form when the browser creates the DOM from your HTML … not inside form, not being send with the form data … and trying to put non-existent POST values into your array then results in the value NULL. (And would result in a PHP `Notice` too, so please set up your PHP error_reporting _properly_ before proceeding.)

Comment: One more thing to add; don't duplicate `id` attributes. You have two sets of `inlineRadio1` and `inlineRadio2`

Comment: @Alex.Ritna the radios are inside the form. They are validated just fine. I have tried everything else. Still POST gives null.

Comment: It's kind of hard to test without your full form. You can use the 2 radios buttons. As Phil mentioned about the duplicate ID's, if you're using that in conjunction with JS/jQuery, that's most likely the issue. Plus, what CBroe said about the form tags; you're not showing any. Show us your full form code.

Comment: Did you mean ``method="post"`` instead of ``type="post"`` on your form element? Probably doesn't affect anything if the browser defaults to post but at least the attribute would be valid.